# Подсчитать количество определенных букв в строке методом reduce

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые форумчане.
Помогите исправить ошибку в коде.
Ошибка, мне кажется, в цикле if, когда он находит вторую 'а' идет ошибка в просчете

```
let getValue = (string, letter) => {
    count = 0;
    let arr = [];
    arr = string.split('').reduce((count, elem) => {
        console.log(elem, letter)
        if (elem === letter) {
            count++;
            console.log(count)
        }
    }, 0)
    return count
}

console.log(getValue('abcabca', 'a'));
```

Comment: Обязательно через `reduce`? А то ведь можно и как-то так: `let getValue = (string, letter) => string.split(letter).length;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас есть две переменных с именем `count`. Одна объявлена внутри `getValue`:

```
count = 0;
```

А другая — параметр стрелочной функции внутри `reduce`:

```
.reduce((count, elem) => ...
```

Второй `count` не имеет никакого отношения к первому. Внутри стрелочной функции вы наращиваете `count`, но это не та переменная, которую вы пытаетесь изменить.

Перепишите так:

```js
let getValue = (string, letter) => {
    let count = 0;
    string.split('').reduce((arg1, elem) => count += elem === letter, 0);
    return count;
};
console.log(getValue('abcabca', 'a'));
```

А ещё лучше так:

```js
let getValue = (string, letter) => {
    return string.split('').reduce((count, elem) => count += elem === letter, 0);
};
console.log(getValue('abcabca', 'a'));
```